# GPG Cannot read contents of source file

Tags: flutter, github, github-actions, gnupg

I am using GitHub secrets to save an encrypted version of my project's .env file, then I use GPG to decrypt the secret when running my GitHub Actions.

```yaml
- name: Some Name
  run: |
    rm -f ./assets/.env

    echo "${{ secrets.ENV }}" > ./env.asc
    gpg --batch --passphrase "${{ secrets.BUILD_TOKEN }}" -d "./env.asc" > "./assets/.env"
```

For some reason, I keep getting the following error when GPG tries to read `./env.asc`.

```
shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
env:
    FLUTTER_ROOT: /opt/hostedtoolcache/flutter/stable-3.3.3-x64
    PUB_CACHE: /opt/hostedtoolcache/flutter/stable-3.3.3-x64/.pub-cache
invalid option "-----BEGIN"
```

Can someone please tell me why I keep getting this error?

Comment: Looks like that problem is being caused by the double quotes around `${{ secrets.ENV }}` as it contains multiline key. Use single quotes around that and retry.